Named Pipes - Buffering and Blocking
Can someone please clarify behavior of the named pipes (particularly in Linux) regarding buffering data and blocking.
mkfifo pipe1

cat pipe1 # blocks until another process sends data

echo "hi" > pipe1 # running this in the other tty unblocks waiting "cat"

and on contrary (this could be run after previous experiment on the same pipe supposedly):
echo "ping" > pipe1 # blocks, seemingly until another process reads the data

cat pipe1 # unblocks the "echo" above, if run from another tty

Do these both examples block until the "other end" is read/written - or just until the other end is opened at all?
Does the pipe have internal buffer (so that some further writing could be done without block)?
If the process on the "reading" end finishes while some data were not yet consumed from the pipe (or the "writing" process send some more before also finishing) - are these extra data going to appear when the next reading process opens the pipe?
Do we recognize some kind of EOF on the reading end when writing process finishes and we consumed all the data it produced (even though later we can reuse the pipe, writing to it from the other process)?
Sorry if questions are not well-relevant due to misunderstanding of the mechanism. Please feel free to simply provide a link to some advanced documentation.

see the specification of open, read and write and search for "fifo"

In your first example
mkfifo pipe1

cat pipe1 

echo "hi" > pipe1 # from another TTY

the program cat is first blocking in open until the other shell opens the FIFO pipe1 for writing as the shell does the redirection.
Depending on the timing, it may block in read until echo has written some data.
When echo ends, its standard output, which is connected to the FIFO, will be closed. This will appear as an end-of-file condition for cat, and it will write remaining output if any and terminate.
In fact this will happen when the last writing process has closed its end of the FIFO.

In the second example
echo "ping" > pipe1

cat pipe1 # from another TTY

the shell will prepare the output redirection for echo. This will block in the open call for the FIFO pipe1 until cat also opens the FIFO.
After opening the FIFO by the shell, it will be connected to echo's standard output, and echo can write the data without blocking because it is less than PIPE_BUF.
Depending on the timing, cat might block in read until echo has actually written something.
If the reading end has been closed by the last process, the writing process will receive a SIGPIPE when it tries to write again.
Any data in the FIFO is discarded when all processes have closed it.
(I did not yet find a specification what will happen when all reading processes have closed the FIFO and a new open for reading happens before any writing process has tried to write.)
See the specification of open, read, write and close and search for "fifo".

Hi and sorry for the delayed response. I figured out the basics but found that issue (because of which I decided to ask this question) is caused by the issue in standard library of certain compier (obcpl) I'm tinkering with - it simply won't flush data. Thanks a lot for explanations anyway!

@RodionGorkovenko If you are using functions from stdio.h, the output is buffered by default. You might have to call fflush if you really need the data to be written immediately.

no, thanks. it's about BCPL implementation "obcpl" it has its own small library implementation. "functions from stdio.h" which you mention may behave differently depending on "isatty" (e.g. for tty output is flushed after newline for example) - but in this obcpl this behavior seeming was intended but is not working.


note that in your first example, cat is not "blocking" the execution of the following echo command, the shell is responsible for that delay because the cat command has not completed.

A most basic use of cat is to replicate input, where you start the command and then "type at it" until you are done with your thoughts. THEN you type a closing Ctrl-D char to close the input to cat. To make this a little more concrete, the example below redirects the output of the cat input into a file, i.e.:
$ cat > myFile
here is some text
another line
Ctrl-D will be typed by itself on the line below, you won't see it in this transcript but `cat` will close its input stream
$ cat myFile
here is some text
another line
Ctrl-D will be typed by itself on the line below, you won't see it in this transcript but `cat` will close its input stream


another method that would allow you to execute the echo "hi" > pipe1 cmd immediately without waiting for cat to close would be to run the first command "in the background" by appending the & char at the end (before any comment chars), i.e.
cat pipe1 &



Given that you are typing input that is then immediately duplicated by the output from your mkfifo pipe1, it's not really a good illustration of using a backgrounded process to feed to a fifo.

The standard method for signalling the end of input via the stdin/stdout stream conventions (via > redirect or | (pipe) ) is to send the Ctrl-D char. It's not clear what is really writing to your mkfifo pipe1, but if is sends a Ctrl-D char, the std-in stream should close.

you wrote "If the process on the "reading" end finishes while some data were not yet consumed from the pipe (or the "writing" process send some more before also finishing) "


I'm not quite clear what your intention is here, but I think my point 3) above covers that issue. Pipes and streams are designed to keep both ends open for reading/writing until the magic-char (Ctrl-D) is sent/received. There are almost certainly other C language functions that are used to close streams as well, but that would require research on your part, based on the needs of your system.
Finally, you may find some programs that don't know to do that, but that should be a rare case.
The Ctrl-D character is generated by holding down the Control Key and pressing the D key on your keyboard. Of course that character can also be programatically generated. man ascii to see appropriate octal/hex values.

Ctrl-D isn’t really magic. It’s a signal to the TTY infrastructure to close a file. It can be disabled via stty/termios to cause it to send a regular character (EOF, ASCII 4).

Thank you for the answer. I see now I probably need to dig more even to be able to ask proper question :) Thanks for the note about "cat" which I seemingly missed or misunderstood. As for Ctrl-D I believe it is not the only way to end the stream. E.g. if I feed some file without Ctrl-D at the end as an input to some program (e.g. with "cat" and pipe symbol), it will see input stream ends even though there is never Ctrl-D...

@nneonneo Ascii 4 is EOT--end of transmission
